# How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?

Tags: android, http

How do I use the `AndroidHttpClient` as an HTTP client to connect to a remote server? I have not been able to find good examples in the documentation nor on the internet.

Comment: This is actually a useful question. There's not a lot of examples of how to use AndroidHttpClient. Maybe the question should be more specific.

Comment: I updated this to make it a real question. Please re-open it because, as you can see, this has been a useful question to many people.

Comment: Are we going to re-open this or what?

Comment: Why? That makes zero sense to me. Sometimes SO completely baffles & frustrates me.

Comment: I reached here by googling *android http client example*. It seems that the above average programmer's questions are real.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
public static void connect(String url)
{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        // Examine the response status
        Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            instream.close();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: your lmgtfy attracted lots of "offensive" flags. I strongly recommend not doing that.

Comment: Got it. Next time I will try to avoid it.

Comment: To make this work with GZIP, chunked stream etc, use the HttpClient and entity.writeTo() instead.

Comment: Should reader or the InputStreamReader be closed?

Comment: Honeycomb and newer will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you try to do this without using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: can you update this ? or this method still valid in 2014 ? or at least give some links to actual methods ?

Comment: This is still valid, but now there are libraries that do this for you. For instance https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

Comment: My app stops at the 'response = httpclient.execute(httpget);' line, eventually times out and goes to 'catch'. its simply hitting a php fiel that returns data in json format.

Comment: HttpClient is now a legacy. You better use OkHttp since Android SDK 23 Marshmallow.

Comment: In order to use this in API > 22  add this to app build.gradle  

`android{
 useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
public static String executeHttpPost1(String url,
            HashMap<String, String> postParameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();

        try{
        request = new HttpPost(url);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(postParameters!=null && postParameters.isEmpty()==false){

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(postParameters.size());
            String k, v;
            Iterator<String> itKeys = postParameters.keySet().iterator();
            while (itKeys.hasNext()) 
            {
                k = itKeys.next();
                v = postParameters.get(k);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));
            }     

            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEntity  = new  UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            request.setEntity(urlEntity);

        }
        try {


            Response = client.execute(request,localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = Response.getEntity();
            int statusCode = Response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.i(TAG, ""+statusCode);


            Log.i(TAG, "------------------------------------------------");





                try{
                    InputStream in = (InputStream) entity.getContent(); 
                    //Header contentEncoding = Response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                    /*if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                        in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                    }*/
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        str.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    in.close();
                    response = str.toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, "response"+response);
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException exc){

                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }


        } catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+response);         

        }
        finally {

        }

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
                conection.connect();
                // Getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                // Create a Input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/sdcard/9androidnet.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();
                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                connectionTimeout=true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.