# basic http connection between wamp and Android 

Tags: java, php, android, wamp, wampserver

I have an app that talks to my wamp server using http req and response .

I have set my serveripaddress as  xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/ and am using it in the app , to ping my database .. ( for ex: user login) ..

But , I don't think the communication is taking place after the click activity ...

What other modifications are required ?

`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serveripaddress.servipaddr+"register.php");`

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

to actually send the request.

Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-example-in-android) for an example of how to work with HTTP operations in Android.

Comment: Do i need to modify some config files to execute it ?? tat was my Question... thx

Comment: @Zac Ah, no.  You don't.  Just make sure you have the `USES_INTERNET` permission listed in your manifest file.