# Android Java - Get plain text from webpage (alert system)

Tags: java, android, webview

What I want to do should be very simple, however I have little to none Java/Android experience.

I have a WebView setup in Eclipse. I want the webpage to go to http://example.com/mypage.php. On that page will be either the text 'OK' or 'ALERT'.

I need to know how to check the page for those words. That will be all that's on the page.

Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-example-in-android

Comment: If you just want to check the result for `OK` or `ALERT`, why do you need the WebView? Can't you just request the url through http and then load your result in a string and `.equals()` that?

Comment: @Nanne, that would work just fine and I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do what you want, though it can be done.  First, define an interface that goes something like:

```
public interface WebInterfaceDelegate {
    public void receivedHtml(String html);
}
```

Then, define a class that you want to expose to the JavaScript runtime in your WebView, something along the lines of:

```
public static class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {
    private WebInterfaceDelegate delegate;

    public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(WebInterfaceDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void htmlLoaded(String html) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.receivedHtml(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, make your `Activity` implement the interface you defined above, like:

```
public class AndroidWebViewActivity extends Activity implements WebInterfaceDelegate {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidAPI");

        webView.loadUrl("http://your.url.com");
    }

    //...

    public void receivedHtml(String html) {
        //inspect the HTML here
        System.out.println("Got html:  " + html);
    }
}
```

Finally, add some JavaScript to your page that goes like:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        AndroidAPI.htmlLoaded(document.body.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

So you can do all that, or you can just use something like `URL.openStream()` to connect directly to your target webpage and read the markup off of the socket instead of off of the `WebView`.  To do this is as simple as:

```
InputStream response = new URL("http://example.com/mypage.php").openStream();
//read the data from the response into a buffer, then inspect the buffer
```

You can find some additional information here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: I looked over all of it, but I don't really need the webview. I tried to find some sort of documentation for URL.openStream() but I couldn't find anything, could you please explain more about that method?

Comment: @DannyF247 - Okay, I added a bit more information about the `URL.openConnection()` approach.  It's much simpler than trying to go through the `WebView`.

Comment: I'm an extreme noob, I really do appreciate your help. I've done that, but I get `code`Unhandled exception type IOException`code`. I've tried adding `throws IOException` part in the `public void onCreate` part but that just gives me more errors. =/