# Use of Web Services

Tags: android

Is it possible to store a applications content in a webpage and retrieve the same from there using another application in android.

Comment: @RBS please make your question more clear , Whats your need and what you have tried ?

Comment: @RenjithKN I need to write an application that stores its content in webpage(for example a simple text "hi") and another application should get that string "hi" from that webpage.

Comment: @RBS Its posible, which one you have tried web service or just a web page

Comment: @RenjithKN Its actually a project given to me and i don't have any idea about how to do it. Give me some suggestions to do it so that i can start my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think web service is the right call for you 
Please  have a look on the following stack links they will give you some ideas,

1. [Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945319/need-tutorials-on-android-web-services?rq=1)
2. [Content from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585996/android-java-get-plain-text-from-webpage-alert-system)

Hopes this helps you :)