# Android - Download HTML file from URL

Tags: android, html, download, android-download-manager

I'm building an app which is supposed to download (and later on) display an html file.

I *don't* need to worry about supporting files like `CSS/JS`.

I enqueue the file via its `URL` (eg. http://www.noodle.com/index.html) to the Android Donwload Manager but the download always fails.

Any ideas how to get the file? Or how to convince the Manager to download it properly?

Comment: do you want to do it via code or just via browser ?

Comment: i need to do it programmatically... so via code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of HTTPClient provided by Android to use it

More details on how to save that to file is available at 
 [How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-example-in-android)