# Android How to trigger an activity without actually start it

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to call a WebView activity inside another activity for checking the URL in that WebView  activity. However, I don't want to actually start that WebView activity, is there a way to do this without actually start WebView activity but I still can be able to check the URL?

Comment: what's the point of making the activity an activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use http client method in async task and execute your url in that and get response from your url in input stream reader    Refer this answer you will get solution of your problem
 [How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-client-example-in-android)

Comment: Could you provide an example for me sir? I appreciate that!

Comment: @Swapnil - please do not badger users to accept your answer, *especially* within the first hour.