# Why is Android truncating my text?

Tags: php, android, textview, truncation

I am writing an Android application that pulls data from a remote database using PHP.  I have PHP code written to download the entire contents of a table to the app.  If I view the PHP in a browser, all of the data is displayed in text form.  However, when I view it in the app, the text is truncated.

Here is the code for the TextView that the data is being fed into:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Any other code will be provided on request, I'm just not sure what else is relevant to this.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks in the browser:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8062829/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-08%20at%202.46.01%20PM.png

And here's a screenshot of how it looks on my device:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8062829/Screenshot_2014-04-08-14-37-09.png

Comment: Share the entire XML.

Comment: Probably a snapshot would help, also.

Comment: Full XML and snapshots added.

Comment: When you logged the results of your HTTP operation to a file, and examined the file, to determine if you successfully downloaded all of the data in Android, what did you learn?

Comment: How do you log the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Athough you haven't provided any code that shows how you retrieve your data I am certain that your problem is with httpclient. You probably aren't reading the entire stream. Checkout an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/simple-http-client-example-in-android)

Comment: Well, you were close.  While I was looking through my code to see what could be wrong with httpclient, I noticed that I had limited the stream to 500 characters in my downloadUrl method.