# What code used to connect Android Application with MySQL in xampp server?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm using eclipse and MySQL in xampp server..
and I want to connect between them.. 
I'm trying this code but I don't know if it is working or not?

and is there any addition thing shall I do ???

```
searchB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            final String URL_create_GPS = "http://10.68.158.106/android_connect/create_GPS.php";   
            final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            }
    });
```

searchB > is the button name in .xml

Comment: It looks like you need to study network programming basics. also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android