# which IP should I use when sending a file from windows to vm using java

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu, file-transfer

I am trying to send a file from Android emulator on Windows to ubuntu.
https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QNJvxXCYOY
[How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android)

These all helped me learn how to send a file through socket, but I am not sure which IP address to use. I set up `ServerSocket` and `Socket`, but the code won't proceed at `socket = ServerSocket.accept()`

I wonder if this is because I am not using the correct IP address. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to send a file from Android emulator on Windows to ubuntu.

So you're running an emulator on Windows and want to send a file from the emulator to another machine running Ubuntu? Then there is no way for us to answer this question exactly, as IP addresses depend on your personal network setup. I would suggest first moving the file form emulator -> Windows, then you can send it like any other file between your machines (you can use `scp` from Ubuntu, or a service like DropBox, etc.)

You can also probably run `ifconfig` on your Ubuntu side to obtain your destination IP.